# How to make React-hook-form Controller validation triggered on blur?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am creating a form with React-Hook-Form.
I have set `useForm({mode: 'onBlur'})` to trigger validation instantly and show error message right after user onBlur an element.
For input text fields, it works fine.
However, it doesn't work with my `<Controller />` element, which wraps an customized `<Select />`.

The following is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useForm, Controller, ErrorMessage } from 'react-hook-form';
import Select from '../../components/UI/Select';

const departmentList = [
    { name: 'PLEASE SELECT', value: '' },
    { name: 'Finance', value: 'FIN' },
    { name: 'IT', value: 'IT' },
    { name: 'Business', value: 'BIZ' }
];

const Form = props => {
    const { register, handleSubmit, control, errors } = useForm({ mode: "onBlur" });

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    }
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
            <div>
                <label>First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name='firstName' ref={register({ required: 'First name cannot be null.' })} />
                <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name='firstName' />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Last Name:</label>
                <input type='text' name='lastName' ref={register({ required: 'Last name cannot be null.' })} />
                <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name='lastName' />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Department:</label>
                <Controller
                    as={<Select options={departmentList} />}
                    control={control}
                    valueName="selected"
                    rules={{ required: 'Department cannot be null.' }}
                    name="department"
                />
                <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name='department' />
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    );
}

export default Form;
```

The following is the `<Select />` element:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Select = props => {
    let optionList = null;

    if(props.options) {
        optionList = props.options.map((o, i) => <option key={i} value={o.value}>{o.name}</option>)
    }

    return (
        <select 
            className="form-control" 
            value={props.value}
            style={props.style} 
            selected={props.selected}
            onChange={props.onChange}
        >
            { optionList }
        </select>
    );
};

export default Select;
```

After clicking on the select, choosing the empty value, and then blur, it doesn't show the error message onBlur.

Is there any way to make the  trigger validation and show error message onBlur? Do I missed anything?

Comment: With the new version of react-hook-form, it works fine just using `useForm({ mode: "onBlur" })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-hook-form` cannot directly direct the `blur` state of select component. Instead what it does is to send in the `onBlur` function to the component passed to controller. You have to receive the prop and add it to your custom select.

```
const Select = props => {
    let optionList = null;

    if(props.options) {
        optionList = props.options.map((o, i) => <option key={i} value={o.value}>{o.name}</option>)
    }

    return (
        <select 
            className="form-control" 
            value={props.selected}
            style={props.style} 
            onChange={props.onChange}
            onBlur={props.onBlur}
        >
            { optionList }
        </select>
    );
};
```

An HTML select by default receives it's value through the `value` property, so the `selected` does not do anything on the select. It is `props.selected` because you have set `valueName` as `selected` on the controller.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lds4gw?file=Select.js)

Comment: Thank you! It works. But I have another question. Now that we have defined `onBlur={props.onBlur]` inside the `<Select />`, but we didn't set onBlur for the controller. How does the onBlur event be passed into the Select component? Is it done by react-hook-form itself by default?

Comment: The Controller would attach an `onBlur` event to whatever is passed to it, that is the only way it can validate things `onBlur`

Comment: I find another problem. The form cannot get the default value of the select. Take your snippet in Stackbitz as example, I click on the select and don't choose anything, then just blur it. the error message still shows up. Even though I set default value for the `<Select />`, it still cannot get the default value and show error message. 
Is there any other properties missing for the default value?

Comment: @edyucheng How did you pass the default value?

Comment: I pass the default value like:  `<Controller as={<Select value='one'/>} ...../>`

Comment: when using `react-hook-form`, you expect values to be controlled by the library, so it can work on validation and submission. This is why [`Controller`](https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller) comes with a `defaultValues` prop